# C++ template OR operator?

Tags: c++, templates

So I need something like an OR operator inside the argument of a template,
e.g. I want to do the following:

```
template <typename T, typename F,
typename = std::enable_if<
!std::is_same<T, Node>::value> or !std::is_same<F, Node>::value>>
```

In other words I need the function to exists when one of the `T` and `F` template class is not `Node`.

But currently that gives me compile error.

PS: I've edited the original question to make it more clear.

Comment: what's `a` and `b`?

Comment: Where is your template?

Comment: ... and what is your compiler error?  If `a` and `b` are constexpr values that can be converted to `bool`, then `a or b` should work.  Otherwise it won't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::disjunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction)

```
std::enable_if<std::disjunction<a, b>::value>
```

However as mentioned in the comments, `a` and `b` must be `constexpr`, not values only known at runtime.

Comment: Cool! (Sees "since C++17", curses because he can't use it yet)

Comment: @AndyG The page has a possible implementation paragraph. Implementing it yourself shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @GillBates: But I don't want to implement it myself.

Comment: If I understand correctly `a` and `b` must be types - not values - that have static const/constexpr  bool `value` value (i.e. `true_type`/`false_type` or traits derived from them).

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

If you need something like the or operator, use it then!

```
std::enable_if<a || b>::type // <-- why wouldn't this work?
```

Here's an example at [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5735602628754ae)